# How to hide directory list in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET 3.5 web site, which is password protected (form authentication). But yesterday I found I was able to browse the list of directories (which is unexpected).

I searched the web, one article said we need to config it in IIS. But I'm a developer and I'm working on my local machine (no IIS installed).

My question is: are there any way to hide them other than IIS configuration? like set web.config?

Answer (score 1):

This must be configured in your webserver - you cannot handle this in the website itself.  Since you are working locally it shouldn't matter that the root directory is browsable.  If you need to be able to control the site in this way you really ought to set up a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have IIS, you're likely working on your local ASP.NET development server (called Cassini possibly?), in which it is only available locally, so no security worries there.

When you deploy your app, you will likely be on an IIS server, so the configuration will be available

Answer (score 1):

Directory browsing in IIS is controlled in the virtual directory/site configuration.

When you deploy your application to a real server you can configure directory browsing there.

Directory browsing on your local machine shouldn't matter, but [this may work for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039152/disable-visual-studio-web-server-directory-browsing)

In IIS6: http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/03/18/603.aspx
In IIS7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In IIS - Website properties, Home Directory tab, untick Directory browsing.

In Cassini (the ASP.NET development server) I don't think it can be turned off. But the server only runs while your debugging.