# Why is Visual Studio Web Server Browsing the directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

this could be seen as a follow-up to [this SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039152/disable-visual-studio-web-server-directory-browsing). Now we have moved on more than a year and ASP.NET MVC2 comes along *without* a default.aspx

I must have done something to my project in that when I hit the root, the server lists the directory and does not route through my default route. The Routing seems to be accepted, though, as calling **/Home** goes to the default action **{controller}/Index**. When I start the ASP.NET MVC2 template, default routing works.

However, I cannot see any differences right now.

What have I done? Deleted some magic setting in the web.config or anything else?

Thanks for any pointers.

EDIT:
This is my route mapping -

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.MapRoute(
    "Link", 
    "link/{id}",
    new { controller = "Link", action = "Index", id = "" },
    new { controller = @"[^\.]*" }
  );
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Post your routing setup in your global.asax here so we can take a look at it to see if you are missing anything.

Comment: Damn, I only get to it on tuesday...wonder if I can prolong the bounty...

Comment: What's your environment? Are you on XP / IIS6 or newer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that resulted in this situation was completely unrelated to ASP.NET MVC. By some incredible c***-up in the solution configuration the web project wasn't built, but the project is started nonetheless, with a stale dll that has nothing to do with your development.

Make sure your app is built and you will most likely see expected results!